# Trying to send value and text of select input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to send the value and the text of a select box input in the php file I'm writing.  I have jquery included. 
I am passing the value in order to query the database, but since the name associated with the records is in another table, and I don't want to do a join, I figure it would be easier to send the name (which has already been retrieved).  I figure the easiest thing to do is to populate the value of a hidden input with something like this:

```
$('#individ option:selected').text()
```

Example

```
echo "<select id='individ' name='individ'>";
echo "<option value='1'>John Smith</option>";
echo "<option value='2'>Jim Dandy</option>";
echo "<option value='3'>Jane Fletcher</option>";
echo "</select><br />";

echo "<input type='hidden' name='selected_name' value=''>"; //the value of this needs to be the text from the select above
```

Comment: you use .val() for form elements, not .text().

Comment: I actually think that I need the text.  The .val()i think would give me the number, not the name.  Is that right?  I want to send the actual name in the hidden input.  But my real question is how to I get that data into the actual input tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#individ').change(function () {
    $('[name="selected_name"]').val($('#individ option:selected').val());
});
```

I don't know if that's what you're trying to do.  I don't see why you couldn't just get the value of the select on post.

If you need to do it without submitting, you're going to have to do some ajax.

Comment: had to change .val() to .text() but worked after that!  Thanks!

Comment: What I needed is both the value and the text.  I don't know how to send both of those with out using a separate input.

Comment: It's better to use `this` instead of querying the DOM again for its own value property.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you're now only concerned with the name, why not assign the name to `option`'s `value` attribute instead?

If you really want the number as the value, you can update the hidden field with onchange event:

```
jQuery('#individ').bind('change', function(e) {
    jQuery('input[name="selected_name"]').val(this.value);
});
```